# I am getting indexout ofboundexception i have 11 records in my db table

Tags: android

```
public class PaySclip extends Activity {
     HashMap<String, String> hashMap;

     String name="",bank,id;
     ArrayList<Login_Vo> login_VosArrayList;
     SqllietDatabaseConnection sqllietDatabaseConnection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_payslip);
        login_VosArrayList=new ArrayList<Login_Vo>();
        sqllietDatabaseConnection=new SqllietDatabaseConnection(PaySclip.this);
        Login_Master_Vo login_Master_Vo=new Login_Master_Vo();

        ArrayList<Login_Master_Vo> login =     sqllietDatabaseConnection.getAll_LoginMaster();

        if(login!= null && login.size() !=0) {


        for(int i=0;i<=login.size();i++){
            Login_Vo login_Vo=new Login_Vo();
            login_Vo.setEMPLOYEE_ID(login.get(i).toString());
            login_VosArrayList.add(login_Vo);
            Log.v("LoginDe====>",""+login_VosArrayList);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Always use for each loops instead of explicit for loops with index to avoid these sort of errors, and it's much faster. Try doing something like

```
for(Login_Vo login_vo : login){
    login_Vo.setEMPLOYEE_ID(login.get(i).toString());
    login_VosArrayList.add(login_Vo);
    Log.v("LoginDe====>",""+login_VosArrayList);
}
```

Comment: see: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/articles/perf-tips.html#Loops, `With an ArrayList, a hand-written counted loop is about 3x faster (with or without JIT), but for other collections the enhanced for loop syntax will be exactly equivalent to explicit iterator usage.`

Answer (score 1):

use `for(int i=0;i<login.size();i++)` instead of `for(int i=0;i<=login.size();i++)`

Answer (score 0):

Change the for loop to..

```
for(int i=0;i<login.size();i++){
            Login_Vo login_Vo=new Login_Vo();
            login_Vo.setEMPLOYEE_ID(login.get(i).toString());
            login_VosArrayList.add(login_Vo);
            Log.v("LoginDe====>",""+login_VosArrayList);
        }
```